# Find all chars occuring 1-3 times

Tags: regex

I'm looking for regex here. I have a partial solution, but it has to be completed. Im looking for a leteral `B` here but I want to look for `[A-Z]` and use backreferences at the according places:

**What I tried**

`^[^B]*(B)(?!(?:[^B]*B){3})` finds the first 'B' if its occuring 1-3 times.
[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QbBnOW/1)

- Matches non `B` 0-n times
- Matches first `B`
- Does not match if there are 3(or more) `B` ahead

**What it should be**

What im looking for is not just match `B`, but match `[A-Z]` - if I try `^[^\1]*([A-Z])(?!(?:[^\1]*\1){3})` (replaced matched `B` with `[A-Z]` and backreferenced it.)

**Problems to solve**

The problem here. `[^\1]` this seems to not work.

I need to negate the backreference and quantify it. 2 things it doesnt wanna do :D

**Desired Results (examples)**

`AAA` result `[A]` because `A` is a `[A-Z]` and no more than 3 times in the string

`AABB` result `[A,B]` because `A` and `B` no more than 3 times

`ABAB` same as `AABB`

`123AABBAA` result `[B]` because `[A-Z]` and no more than 3 times

**EDIT**

Something that may help: `(?:(?<=(?!\1)))*` as replacement for `[^\1]*`
[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QbBnOW/4)

Kind of works returns `A` on `(A)AA` and no match on `AAAA` but wont match `BAAA` (which should redsult in `[a,b]`)

Comment: `[^\1]` matches any char but a char with hex value `\x01`. You need [`^.*?([A-Z])(?!(?:(?:(?!\1).)*\1){3})`](https://regex101.com/r/QbBnOW/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew unfortunately this does not do the trick. It matches `A(AAA)` where it shouldnt match. But thx for participating!

Comment: I doubt regex can help here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please have a look at the edit, maybe this helps?

Comment: Your edit says `(?:(?<=(?!\1)))*`, which allows for an infinite number of zero-width instances. That's dangerous, though most regex engines will safely realize it as ludicrous. I don't think the lookbehind is needed. [`([A-Z])(?:(?!\1).)+` (explanation)](https://regex101.com/r/1PoQUE/1) will find letters that are not repeated, thus representing your desired `([A-Z])[^\1]+` intention.

Comment: Could you supply a list of examples that you want this regex to hit and examples you want this regex to avoid? That would help us determine how to help you.

Comment: @AdamKatz added examples - and thanks for explaining infinite zero with instances, didnt notice O_O

Comment: What language/environment is this regex being executed in?